# Deleted Answers not Disappearing

Tags: support, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

In my question, on the main U&L site: [Check if SSH is Enabled or Disabled in Solaris 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/check-if-ssh-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-solaris-11), I have deleted my own answer, but it hasn't disappeared. **Why has it not gone?** It has gone red though.

I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't see this type of question asked anywhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* gone (that's why it is red), but you are allowed to still see it, and edit or undelete it if you so wish.

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> Self-deleted answers can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

Comment: Ah great, that is slightly confusing though.

Comment: Note that  users with 10K or higher rep can see them too.